# Insert multiple columns into one MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a select query that brings me 8 columns:

```
SELECT
substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-7),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-6),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-5),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-4),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-3),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-2),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-1),',',1)
FROM `dump`)
```

and I want to insert them all into a single column in another table, so I'm trying to do but **not merge** them together, instead each one would go into a new row, so what I tried to do was:

```
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT
substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-7),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-6),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-5),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-4),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-3),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-2),',',1),
substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-1),',',1)
FROM `dump`))
```

Is there a way to do that on MySQL alone?

Comment: Have you tried using `UNION` and one `SELECT` query per one of your substrings?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) 
VALUES ((SELECT substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',1) FROM `dump`));
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-7),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-6),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-5),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-4),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-3),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-2),',',1)FROM `dump`))
INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES (
(SELECT substring_index(substring_index(`Cuisines`,',',-1),',',1) FROM `dump`))
```

Comment: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row `

Comment: I've edited your answer, you didn't need `VALUES` in there.